# Using palette fill/colors in ggplot2 for regression lines and such

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am looking for a way to have regression lines and other things I may wish to overlay on the graph take the next available color from the palette. For instance, suppose I am plotting `mpg` vs `cyl` in the `mtcars` dataset. I consider each of the `cyl` as distinct samples so I am using a qualitative color palette, but I add a regression line under the hypothesis that fuel efficiency is a linear function of cylinders.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8))
p
```

You get this plot:

[image: plot]

I would like the regression line color to keep with the theme. I could figure out that the next color in this series should be `C77CFF`, but what if I change the theme?

```
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: stuff]

Is there a way to have the `geom_smooth` automatically grab the next color in the palette? Or how about just grabbing the Nth color? After exploratory data analysis, I know how many classes are in my data and I'm fine with hardcoding that. I'd just like an easier way to go through different color palettes.

Comment: You can use `scale_*_manual` for colours and fill, with the manual colors supplied by `scales::brewer.pal` or `scales::hue.pal`. For example, `scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Spectral")(5)` yields a vector of five colors, "#D7191C" "#FDAE61" "#FFFFBF" "#ABDDA4" "#2B83BA".

Comment: Brian, I don't think that answers my question. I can always change the fill/color to something manually, but I am looking for a way to have the `geom_smooth` to automatically get updated depending upon whatever palette I add. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve it is to use only colour aesthetics, not both colour and fill. Notice that by changing the outlines of the violins, rather than their fill, we can manually add another color level, called "Regression", inside the `aes()` of the smoother. This is robust to changing the palette as well, see below with examples.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_violin(aes(colour = factor(cyl)), size = 2) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(color = "Regression"), size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8))
```

[image]

[image]

But if you want to be able to mix fills and colors within the same palette, you need to use a solution like my comment above.

```
numbrk <- 4
# Your number of categories, known a priori, plus one

mypal <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = "YlGnBu")(numbrk)
# Now you just have to put in your chosen palette once
# "#FFFFCC" "#A1DAB4" "#41B6C4" "#225EA8"

fillpal <- mypal[1:(numbrk-1)]
colpal <- mypal[numbrk]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(color = "Regression")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fillpal) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colpal)
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick. You can also expand on it by setting color and fill for the violin plots and the smoothed lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as easier, but you can create a function like the following one to achieve your desired result:

```
palette_plot <- function(df, x_var, y_var, chosen_palette) {
  num_levels <- nlevels(as.factor(df[[x_var]]))
  line_color <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = chosen_palette)(num_levels + 1)
  line_color <- line_color[[num_levels + 1]]
  fill_var   <- as.factor(df[[x_var]])

  ggplot(df) +
    aes_string(x_var, y_var) +
    geom_violin(aes(fill = fill_var)) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.5) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = line_color) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = chosen_palette)
}
```

Testing the "Pastel2" palette.

```
 palette_plot(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg", "Pastel2")
```

[image]